# How do I create a responsive excel document title using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I have successfully got a function built where I can gather some data, convert it to a dataframe, and then convert it into an excel document.  The problem I am having is, I don't know how to create a responsive title name or storage location.  I have the path using pandas hard coded like so:

```
developmentdata = pd.DataFrame(dev_names).to_excel(r'C:\Desktop\Dev\devproj\test.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

and the excel is titled 'test.xlsx'.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the title you want as a variable?

Comment: Being able to get a title based on a variable would be useful.  For instance these are variables I have.

    language = php

    location = boston


Also using now from the time module would be useful too

Ideally I would have a title that would be something like boston_php_8192019.  I just don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python offers many different possibilities for programmatically constructing text strings. A modern approach that I personally would recommend is to use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). There are also many different possibilities to construct and format dates, but I think that python's [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module should suit your needs. As an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Variables with identifying information
output_dir = r"C:\Desktop\Dev\devproj"
language = "php"
location = "boston"

# Retrieve current date as a formatted string
current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Construct output path using f-strings
file_name = f"{location}_{language}_{current_date}.xlsx"
output_path = rf"{output_dir}\{file_name}"

print(output_path)
# Output:
# C:\Desktop\Dev\devproj\boston_php_20190821.xlsx
```

*Note 1*: to use f-strings you must have python 3.6 or higher.

*Note 2*: for dates in file names I'd always recommend to use "year-month-day" formatting (as done in the code example). This has the benefit that when you sort multiple of these files by name, you automatically get a proper chronological sorting as well.

Comment: I created a method that ended up working, but I like this.  Thank you for answering it.  I am going to do more research into f-strings as I have only just started hearing about them, but they seem useful.